# create multidimensional array or object in jquery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

this is what I've got and been struggeling for hours. if I `alert(i)`in the each loop it gives me `1,2,3...` but if I want to use as as key for a multidimensional array it is like a string `"i"`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var positions=[];

    $( ".box" ).each(function(i) {
        //alert(i);
        var elPositions = {};
        elPositions.i = $(this).offset().top;
        positions.push(elPositions);
        //$elPosArray[i] = $(this).offset().top;
        //$(this).html('outer height--> ' + $(this).outerHeight(true));
    });
    console.log(positions);
    //console.log(el);
});
```

There are Questions and answers to this topic but none of them helped me to get this to work.

I would like to get an array or obj looking something like:

```
   positions[0]['offset'] = '120';
   positions[0]['height'] = '300';
   positions[1]['offset'] = '420';
   positions[1]['height'] = '180';
   positions[2]['offset'] = '600';
   positions[2]['height'] = '100';
   positions[3]['offset'] = '700';
   positions[3]['height'] = '300';
```

Here is a fiddle with the html http://jsfiddle.net/Z9WrG/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're pretty much there!

In your loop, `elPositions` (here renamed `data`) is recreated new on each iteration, and then pushed into the array with a consecutive index. There's no need to specify `i` in the data object as `i` is assigned automatically when you push into the array.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9WrG/2/

and code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var positions=[];

    $( ".box" ).each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var data = {};

        data.offset = $this.offset().top;
        data.height = $this.height();

        positions.push(data);
        // Now, positions[iteration_index] = { offset: x, height: y }
    });

    console.log(positions);
    console.log(positions[0].height);
    console.log(positions[0].offset);
});
```

Comment: I know, I know, I shouldn't say thanks here. BUT THANKS ZOUGEN :-) awesome, also for telling what I was doing wrong!

Comment: @caramba - There is nothing wrong with thanking someone for help in the comments ;) The general stance is don't add thanks at the end of your question so it's as clear and concise as possible.

Comment: @Josh Harrison Thank you very much.